# Error de al intentar conectarme a una web con httplib en python?

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy intentando conectar un script de python con una web simple que yo mismo hice en html y php para probar por medio de httplib.

El escript de python para la conexion es el siguiente:

```
import http.client as ht
import urllib.parse as ub 

openConn=ht.HTTPConnection('127.0.0.1:80')
headers = {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Accept':'text/plain'}
param = ub.urlencode({'usertext':'jhona','passtext':'shaki11'})
openConn.request('GET','http://localhost/Test_brut/html_te/php/backdoc.php',param,headers)
resp=openConn.getresponse()
read_resp=resp.read().decode()
print(read_resp)
```

El documento php que recibe la conexion es el siguiente:

```
$username = $_GET['usertext'];
$password = $_GET['passtext'];

if(isset($username)&& $username=='jhona'){
if(isset($password) && $password == 'shaki11'){

    $open_file = fopen('script_ht.html','r');
    $read_f='';

    while(!feof($open_file)){
        $lin=fgets($open_file);
        $read_f=$read_f.$lin;
    }

    fclose($open_file);

    echo 'WELCOME '.$username.'<br>'.$read_f;
}

else{
    echo "THE PASS IS INCORRECT";
}

}
else{
    echo 'No exist';
}
```

sin embargo cuando lo intento el `getresponse()` de `httplib.client` me arroja la respuesta el siguiente error:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: usertext in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Test_brut\html_te\php\backdoc.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: passtext in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Test_brut\html_te\php\backdoc.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
No exist
```

Se que el error esta en el script de python y no en el documento php debido a que cuando me conecto desde una pagina HTML ingresando el usuario y la clave obtengo el mensaje de Bienvenida, pero cuando lo hago desde el script de python obtengo el error.

Alguien aqui sabe que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema está en la línea:

```
openConn.request('GET','http://localhost/Test_brut/html_te/php/backdoc.php',param,headers)
```

pues [según la documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPConnection.request) el tercer parámetro, en el que tú estás pasando `param`, sería el *body* de la petición, el cual tiene sentido sólo para peticiones tipo POST o PUT pero debe ser `None` (su valor por defecto) en las tipo GET.

En una petición GET los parámetros han de ser parte de la URL, y por tanto tendrías que prepararla previamente, con algo como:

```
param = ub.urlencode({'usertext':'jhona','passtext':'shaki11'})
url = 'http://localhost/Test_brut/html_te/php/backdoc.php?' + param
```

para seguidamente hacer la petición con:

```
openConn.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
```

### Edición

Te recomiendo instalar la librería `requests` que hace mucho más sencillo este tipo de cosas:

```py
import requests

url = 'http://localhost/Test_brut/html_te/php/backdoc.php'
params = {'usertext':'jhona','passtext':'shaki11'}
resultado = requests.get(url, params=params)

if resultado.ok:
    print(resultado.content)
else:
    print("Error {}: {}".format(resultado.status_code, resultado.reason)
```