# Error al intentar loguearme en una web con httplib en python?

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy intentando loguearme en una web por medio de un script de python con httplib pero me arroja un error `socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed.`

El script de logueo de python es el siguiente:

```
import http.client as ht
import urllib.parse as ub 

openConn=ht.HTTPConnection('https://www.facebook.com:443')
headers = {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Accept':'text/plain'}
param = ub.urlencode({'email':'usuario.75@gmail.com','pass':'password332'})
openConn.request('POST','https://www.facebook.com/login/device-based/regular/login/?login_attempt=1&lwv=110',param,headers)
resp=openConn.getresponse()
read_resp=resp.read().decode()
print(read_resp)
```

Como notaran tome como ejemplo el logueo en la web de facebook para intentarlo pero el error completo que me arroja es el siguiente:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\http_connect_2.py", line 7, in <module>
    openConn.request('POST','https://www.facebook.com/login/device-based/regular/login/?login_attempt=1&lwv=110',param,headers)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 936, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socket.py", line 704, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

Como puedo resolver este error?, no tengo mucha experiencia en el area web.

Comment: ¿Por qué esta pregunta se parece tanto a [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/294639/7123)? Casi tienen el mismo código, pero el problema es completamente diferente. De todas formas, a `HTTPConnection()` tienes que pasarle un nombre de host, no una URL, por tanto en tu parámetro sobra el esquema (https) y el número de puerto. Además, ya que intentas conectar por el protocolo https, no debes usar `HTTPConnection` sino `HTTPSConnection()`. No necesitas pasarle el puerto ya que 443 es el estándar para ese tipo de conexión.

Comment: Por otro lado, reitero lo que se te respondió en tu otra pregunta. Todo es más sencillo si usas la biblioteca `requests`, pues en ella sí puedes pasar directamente la URL con el esquema http ó https. Por cierto, que no has comentado ni puntuado ni aceptado la respuesta a la otra pregunta ¿te sirvió?

Comment: @abulafia  Si de hecho estoy haciendo muchas preguntas relacionadas con ese mismo codigo por que tengo que hacer muchas pruebas relacionadas con httplib.. Respecto a tu recomendacion, si la tome en cuenta pero digamos que en este momento no busco lo mas facil sino poder comprender el funcionamiento de la web. Igual mente gracias por ser tan activo en las respuestas.